# log4j practical question

Tags: java, logging, log4j

log4jRefreshInterval
    1000

I have used while configuring log4j to my web.xml.I am using spring. I saw that this is only used to detemine the property changes when app running.

I thought this is optional,

but without this my logging is not work

Comment: What error do you get when you try it without log4jRefreshInterval?

Answer (score 0):

Promoted to answer OP's comment:

No error, It didn't logging, After adding  log4jRefreshInterval 1000   org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener  I start to work